# Combine two specific SQL statements

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

**Table F:**

```
Field F_ID

Field F_T_ID (foreign key)
```

**Table T:**

```
Field T_ID
```

I have a F_ID, so I can find the matching table T:

```
SELECT * FROM F INNER JOIN T ON F_T_ID = T_ID WHERE F_ID = x
```

Then I can find all tables F that refer to that table T:

```
SELECT * FROM F WHERE F_T_ID = y
```

How can I do this in one SQL statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the first query will ever only return one (or no) rows then you can use the first query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM F WHERE F_T_ID = 
    (SELECT F_T_ID FROM F INNER JOIN T ON F_T_ID = T_ID WHERE F_ID = x)
```

Comment: Aah, a "Subquery or Inner query or Nested query". I did not know of this. Thank you both for the answer, and excuse my SQL ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean all the F's that refer to the same T as your F_ID? how about this:

```
SELECT F1.*
  FROM F F1
  JOIN T ON T.T_ID = F1.F_T_ID
  JOIN F ON F.F_T_ID = T.T_ID
        AND F.F_ID = x
```

If you don't want to include the original F you could add this:

```
WHERE F1.F_ID != x
```

Comment: Aah, a "Subquery or Inner query or Nested query". I did not know of this. Thank you both for the answer, and excuse my SQL ignorance.